# SharePoint Online Append-Only Comments field is duplicated every time Microsoft Flow runs

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, append-changes

I have created a Flow which updates various fields in my SharePoint Online list, one of them being an Append-Only Comments field.  This comment field is only updated sometimes.  In scenarios where I don't want to add a new comment, the comment from the previous run is duplicated with a newer timestamp.

How can I avoid this occuring in Microsoft Flow?

Comment: What type of field is comments column??

Comment: Is it a required field? In your flow, when you dont want to update the field, do not pass anything in the field in update item action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cases where you do not want to update the comments field in Flow, Try using a dynamic expression to explicitly set that column value to `null` in the Item Update.